# Is it possible to use the Vaadin Collaboration Engine with Fusion?

Tags: vaadin, hilla, vaadin-fusion

The Vaadin [Collaboration Engine](https://vaadin.com/collaboration) for real-time collaboration only has example for Vaadin Flow. Can you use it with Vaadin Fusion?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's currently no support for using Collaboration Engine directly from Fusion, but there are two ways of getting partial benefits already today. These are just theoretical ideas, I haven't tested either of them in practice.

The first approach is to use Flow to configure and control the components that should have collaborative features, and then use `WebComponentExporter` to make them available as web component that can be used from Fusion. This might be quite practical for the avatar group and the upcoming discussion features, but not so much for form binding.

The second approach is to use the low-level data synchronization Java APIs from Collaboration Engine and expose those through Fusion endpoints (with a separate push channel). You could then use that data synchronization layer to implement your own component integrations.

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible at this time, but [Fusion support](https://github.com/vaadin/platform/issues/1998) is on [the roadmap](https://github.com/orgs/vaadin/projects/9).

As Leif mentioned, it's possible to create a Flow component for the needed collaboration features, and then export that as a web component that can be embedded in a Fusion view. A demo of this can be found [on GitHub](https://github.com/eriklumme/fusion-ce-demo).